# Tuning receive ACK timeout on Linux for Webserver

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, latency

I work with remote sensing equipment for a particular university's environmental sciences department and am having trouble with latency. We have sensors in the field that periodically send updates (as POSTs) back into a box running linux and a simple web server. The devices connect via a daisy chain of wireless repeaters (we're experimenting with shortwave as an alternative to commercial cellular networks).

Our problem comes from high latency in some of our links; approaching 20 seconds. Our sensors are unable to complete the threeway handshake to establish the connection to the server. We see the SYN get to the server and then the SYNACK get back to the remote, but by the time the ACK gets to the server from the remote the server has already sent a RST.

Is there a way to tune the linux TCP stack so that the timeout for receiving these ACK's can be lengthened?

Comment: Interesting problem, but beyond my pay-grade. Maybe add a tag for the language you're programming `c`, `c++`, or ?? and the pros will notice your Q. (notice the relatively low "followers" for `tcp` and `latency` tags). Good luck.

Comment: Perhaps UDP would be a better transport mechanism for this application?  Then you would have full control over all timeout/resend/give-up mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is related to RTO.

See RFC6298 2.1. Until a round-trip time (RTT) measurement has been made for a segment sent between the sender and receiver, the sender SHOULD set RTO <- 1 second.

See RFC6298 5.5. The host MUST set RTO <- RTO * 2

My Ubuntu(14.04)'s "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries" is set to 5.

In other words,

```
Server state.
1. SYN/ACK First Send ===> 1 second wait ...
2. SYN/ACK Retransmission ===> 2 second wait ...
3. SYN/ACK Retransmission ===> 4 second wait ...
4. SYN/ACK Retransmission ===> 8 second wait ...
5. SYN/ACK Retransmission ===> 16 second wait ...
6. SYN/ACK Retransmission ===> 32 second wait ...
```

Above total wait time is longer than 20 seconds.

Try "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries" changing.